# Get build information from Jenkins API

Tags: rest, jenkins

I'm writing a Jenkins plugin and I want to retrieve last build information (number, timestamp) for a given job from Jenkins api. I can do following REST call and obtain it.

```
<url_to_jenkins>job/<job name>/api/json?tree=builds[number,status,timestamp,id,result]
```

Since my plugin is also deployed inside Jenkins is there a way to get this info by calling direct JAVA api instead of this REST call ?

Comment: it seems like it only support remote API, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API. I think it makes more sense as HTTP APIs provides more flexibility :)

Comment: Thanks Sameera... Yes they are flexible and useful if the message passing is done between two systems. but here it happened within the same system. Means i can directly access Jenkins (Hudson.* packages) from my plugin. No real docs for that :(.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins java docs are available [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin). These apis can also be used along with groovy script directly. If you want to use Postbuild groovy script plugin, you can access the build with `manager`. Below is a sample code snippet which disables a build if it is unsuccessful

```
if (manager.build.result.isWorseThan(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)) {
manager.build.project.disabled = true
}
```

You can have look at [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) for more details

Answer (score 0):

From java code it should looks like:
1) get item: Jenkins.getInstance().getItem("jobName")
2) check that item is instanceof some job type (or just Abtract) and cast
3) then just call .getLastBuild() on this object
4) this will be a build object (AbstractBuild) where you can get id, date, result and etc.